# How can I numerically solve an equation with Sympy?

Tags: sympy

I am interested in one solution, not all. As an example, take

```
# Circle with radius 3, infinitely many solutions
x^2 + y^2 = 9
```

There are two nice solutions because the values are integers (x=3, y=0 and x=0, y=3), but I would be fine with any solution.

### What I tried

```
from sympy import nsolve, Eq, symbols

x, y = symbols("x y")
eq = Eq(x**2 + y**2, 9)
print(nsolve(eq, [x, y], [0, 0]))
```

but I get

```
ValueError: expected a one-dimensional and numerical function
```

I also tried

```
print(nsolve([eq], [x, y], [0, 0]))
```

but got

```
NotImplementedError: need at least as many equations as variables
```

Is sympy not able to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

`nsolve` (as the error message says) cannot solve a single equation in two variables. You must add a second equation involving one or both of the symbols

```
>>> list(nsolve((eq,x),(x,y),(0,1)))  # 2nd equation is x = 0
[0, 3.00000000000000]
>>> list(nsolve((eq,x-1),(x,y),(0,1)))  #...x = 1
[1.00000000000000, 2.82842712474619]
>>> list(nsolve((eq,x-y/2),(x,y),(0,1)))  # x = y/2
[1.34164078649987, 2.68328157299975]
```